# Core 2.0 Account Controller Location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've set up a new .net Core 2.0 Web app with individual accounts. I see the links to AccountController, however this controller and views are nowhere to be found.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
</li>
```

[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core Identity? That sounds like the "ASP.NET Core Default UI" BS they had the terrible idea of doing

Comment: brand new project => Authentication => Individual User Accounts

Comment: So you are. The new Identity UI package has all the default code in a NuGet package you are referencing. Look for a `AddDefaultUI` call in the Startup class

Comment: How does one modify views etc?

Comment: Either follow something [like this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/) or create an empty project and manually scaffold Identity, though I'm not sure if that's an option anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They contained in a nuget package. If you want to customize them then you "scaffold" them out of the page, and into source files in your profile, by right clicking on your project, then choosing Add, then New Scaffold Item. In the dialog that appears you'll see Identity.

Note that once you scaffold and customize you're responsible for updating the scaffolded code if there are security bugs.

Comment: blowdart is correct, all those files you're looking for are bundled up in the dll and you'll never see them. If you elect the 'scaffold' option (as suggested), you can elect to get any or all of the functionality in full view. They will be generated in your project in the Areas/Identity/Pages (as Razor Pages). You can also roll these on your own if, say, you wanted them as MVC types, but that'll take some effort.